# C : Veryfing that a parameter is an int parameter

Tags: c, function

In my program, i need to verify that the parameter passed to the program is an integer, so i created this little function to handle the case where user typed "1st" instead of "1".

The problem is that it doesn't work at all. I try the debug and all i can tell you is that the parameters are 12 and the long is 2. (12 is the value i want to test, and 2 is the number of the numbers passed to the function)

```
 int intOnly(char *toCheck, int longeur) {
 int i = 0; 
 while (i < longeur) {
  switch (toCheck[i]) {
   case 0:
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
   case 7:
   case 8:
   case 9:
   case ' ': 
    i++;
   default:
    return 0;
    break;
  }
  return 1;
 }
}
```

I hope that everything is clear,
Thanks for you help ;)

Comment: `long` is a keyword, you can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: With the space in there, this code will accept "2 3 1" (after you change `0` to `'0'`, etc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to check if a character is one of the ten digits, you need to use the character constants `'0'`, `'1'`, etc. (not integer constants, `0`, `1`, etc.).

Answer (score 8):

Once you've fixed the problems that have already been pointed out, you should probably look up `isdigit` and `isspace` and use them to write the function much more cleanly. Another possibility would be to use something like `strcspn` or `strpbrk` to do the search in a single step.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `strtol` this will convert the integer and you can tell from the third param if it succeeded.

For description see [strtol(3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strtol)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm surprised that your code gets past compiling, with a variable named long. However, your real issue is that you're using the numbers 0-9, rather than the characters `'0'` through `'9'` in your switch.

Comment: i modified it because it was a french variable name, so in my code i actually do not have "long" :)

Comment: The English translation would be `length`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add a `break;` statement after the `i++;` statement. Otherwise, you will always 'fall' through the `default` branch and return a 0.

UPDATE: [this is an old question, but for the sake of completeness]

In addition to the missing `break` statement, it is also not cleat how you treat the case where the user enters a string containing a space between digits: `123 456`. Your function identifies this as an integer, but I think this should flag an error.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, consider using `isdigit` instead. Also consider renaming your function to reflect what it really does (such as `intsAndSpacesOnly`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isdigit` and `isspace` function as:

```
int intOnly(char *toCheck, int len) { // long is reserved word..use len.
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < len) {
        if(!isdigit(toCheck[i]) && !isspace(toCheck[i]))
            return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Also **long** is a keyword which you cannot use as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your life easier and your code shorter if you use [ctype.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctype.h), specifically the isdigit or

```
if(toCheck[i] >= '0' && toCheck[i] <= '9' || toCheck[i] == ' '){
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean a positive integer, as your code will fail if negative numbers are passed in, similarly if exponents are passed in (e.g., 1000 as 1e3). The latter is probably rare you'd need to worry about, but the former may be something to think about - I don't know for what purpose you're validating, but just a heads-up :-)